# Graphical dependence in the DAG X->Z<-Y

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence, graphical-model

In Barber's [book](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Barber/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Brml.Online) pp. 40-41 he says that the belief network X->Z<-Y:
[image: graph]

is "graphically dependent" since:

$$p(x,y|z) \propto p(z|x,y)p(x)p(y)$$

I don't understand why graphical dependence follows from the above equation? Is it because we don't see $p(x,y|z)\propto p(x|z)p(y|z)$?

Further, in a similar example he also says that the same graph represents $p(x,y)=p(x)p(y)$, i.e. that $x$ and $y$ are independent, which I assume follow from the definition: $p(x,y,z)=p(z|x,y)p(x)p(y)$.

Is he saying that $x$ and $y$ are independent, but dependent when conditioned on $z$?

Why is $x$ and $y$ graphically dependent in the above graph?

Comment: In that picture, if an arrow connects two nodes they seem to be unconditionally dependent. Then $X$ and $Y$ are independent because no arrow connects them, explaining why $p(x,y)$ factors as $p(x)p(y)$. Using that fact and properties of conditional probability we have , $P(x,y|z)=P(x,y,z)/P(z)=P(x)p(y)p(z,x,y)/p(z)$ which is the proportionality claim. $X$ and $Y$ are unconditionally independent but conditional on $Z$ they are dependent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term "graphical dependence" seems to be specific to Barber's book. I have not seen it anywhere else. I think by graphical dependence, he means that there are arrows connecting variables together. So, the connected variables *appear* to be dependent. But actually they may or may not. They are just dependent (connected) graphically.

In the graph, $x\rightarrow z \leftarrow y$, you have $x \not\perp y | z$ because you cannot get $p(x|z)p(y|z)$ from $p(x,y|z)$, as you said. In words, $x$ and $y$ are not conditionally dependent given $z$. In this graph, it is true that $x\perp y$. That is, $x$ is (marginally) independent of $y$ because

$p(x,y,z) = p(x)p(y) p(z|x,y)$

$p(x, y) = \sum_z p(x,y,z) = p(x)p(y) \overbrace{\sum_z p(z|x,y)}^1 = p(x)p(y).$

This graph kind of structure where there are two arrows pointing two one variable is called a V-structure. $z$ is also called a collider node.

A good concrete example to illustrate the concept is as follows. Imagine $x$ and $y$ are two independent coins with arbitrary probabilities for heads. Let $z \in \{0, 1\}$ where $z=1$ if $x=y$ and $z=0$ if $x\neq y$. By design, $x$ and $y$ are independent. So, $x \perp y$. Now assume $z=1$. Given $z=1$, it can be seen that knowing $x$ reveals the value of $y$. If $x=1$, you can deduce that $y=1$ because $z=1$ means $x$ and $y$ are the same. Here, given $z$ you  know more about $y$ by observing $x$ and vice versa. This effect is called "explaining away". Hence, $x \not\perp y | z$. In this example, we did not put any randomness in $z|x,y$. However, the principle is the same even with stochasticity.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks! What exactly are we actually "explaining away" in your example?

Comment: Perhaps see https://web.eecs.umich.edu/srg/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/pami93.pdf just the first 3 paragraphs.